# How to avoid a option from select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, select

When I am selecting size,I am getting size options like this. 
I want to avoid size its option (orange colored background). How to avoid that.

This is how I get select option:

[image]

I want to avoid a size from this.

This is my select code.

```
<%= select_tag "standard_size_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@standard_sizes, "id", "name"), class: ' form-control', prompt: 'Size' %>
```

Any help is appreciated.

**if I avoid prompt it appers like this.**

[image]

I want a size option also.

Comment: try to create your own select box using jquery. Default select box doesn't have this feature. Help link: http://lewisgaley.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-make-a-custom-form-select-list/

Comment: In jquery on hover you can check if($(this).val() === ''){ //set background color none} else { //set background color}

Comment: here you go.. try this: https://jsfiddle.net/wh6f7031/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are wanting a "Size" option as a blank, but you DON'T want it selected as the default. The only way to get around this is to specify a different default. How about picking the first, like so:

```
= select_tag "standard_size_id", 
             options_from_collection_for_select(@standard_sizes, "id", "name", @standard_sizes.first), 
             class: 'form-control', 
             prompt: 'Size'
```

Comment: please check my edited code . what happens if i remove prompt

Comment: I am confused by your question. Do you actually want "Size" as a blank option in the select list, or not? Is it that you want the a different default selected?

Comment: i want size as default option.

Comment: But isn't that what you had originally with:

= select_tag "standard_size_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@standard_sizes, "id", "name"), class: ' form-control', prompt: 'Size'

Comment: here default size option is not visible.

Comment: OK, so you want a Size option, but not have it selected as the default?

Answer (score 0):

the below is work for me instead `include_blank: true` use the following

```
= select_tag "standard_size_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@standard_sizes, "id", "name"), class: ' form-control', include_blank: 'Size'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a "placeholder" indicating the action to take, but it should not be shown in the list of selectable options.

That cannot be accomplished with standard `select`, because the only way to show a "placeholder" with a `select` is by offering a "blank option" (which is always selectable).

However, there is a library [select2](https://select2.github.io) which offers a dropdown box with more versatile options, including specifying [placeholders](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#placeholders)

In short, you define your select box as before (without the blank/prompt option) and then apply `select2` as follows:

```
$("#standard_size_id").select2({
  placeholder: "Select a size"
});
```